# Flajolet & Sedgewick: symbolic inclusion-exclusion example error?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, inclusion-exclusion, analytic-combinatorics

I'm reading Analytic Combinatorics by Flajolet and Sedgewick, and I have an issue with the following argument from page 208:

[image: Symbolic inclusion-exclusion example]

The authors claim to derive $P(z, u) = e^{(u-1)z}/(1-z)$, the "BGF of permutations where $u$ marks the number of fixed points", except... that's false, right? It works for $u=0$ but when you substitute $u=1$ the result is $P(z, 1) = 1/(1-z)$, which would imply all permutations have exactly 1 fixed point.

Did I read this section incorrectly? The argument makes sense I think, so I don't understand why it is wrong. Does anyone know how to correct the given argument to derive the true form of $P(z, u)$?

Comment: "the result is $P(x,1) = 1/(1-z)$ which would imply all permutations have exactly 1 fixed point". Why makes you think so?

Comment: Because $P(z, u)$ is stated to be "BGF of permutations where $u$ marks the number of fixed points" so I expect substituting $u=1$ to give the EGF of permutations with 1 fixed point, but the result is unexpectedly equivalent to the EGF of all permutations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're misinterpreting the result of substituting different values of $u$ into the BGF.

Here BGF is
$$
P(z,u) = \sum_{n,k} \frac{1}{n!} P_{n,k} z^n u^k,
$$
where $P_{n,k}$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ fixed points.

Substituting $u = 0$ gives
$$
P(z,0) = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{n!} P_{n,0}z^n, 
$$
the EGF of permutations with $0$ fixed points (derangements).

However, substituting $u=1$ gives
$$
P(z,1) = \sum_{n,k} \frac{1}{n!} P_{n,k} z^n = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{n!} \bigg(\sum_{k} P_{n,k}\bigg) z^n = \sum_n z^n, 
$$
the EGF of all permutations, not those with $1$ fixed point.

Similarly, substituting $u=k$ **will not** give an EGF of permutations with $k$ fixed points. The latter is in fact equal to
$$
\frac{1}{k!}\frac{\partial^k}{\partial u^k} P(z,0).
$$

Comment: > substituting $u = 1$ gives [...] the EGF of all permutations, not those with 1 fixed point.

Comment: (sorry accidentally entered the above comment too early)
Yeah, I agree with that. What I mean is the text in the book seems to disagree with that when it says $P(z, u)$ is the "BGF of permutations where $u$ marks the number of fixed points". What I want to know is, (1) what is the "real" interpretation of $P(z, u)$ as derived, since it clearly isn't what I expect based on the text, and (2) Is there a similar argument to the one provided that can derive the "true" form of $P(z, u)$ that you state at the end.

Comment: I've gone and re-read the section III.4 "Inherited parameters and exponential MGF" and I think maybe now I understand my error. IIUC (now) we always need to make the $\frac{1}{k!} \frac{\partial^k}{\partial u^k}$ correction in the case of an exponential MGF. Substituting u directly (like for ordinary MGF) isn't a thing. So yeah I was misinterpreting it as you said.

Comment: @Brocellous, from your "the book seems to disagree" and "it clearly isn't what I expect" I guess you just have to read the book better. It's big, I know. But it explains everything brilliantly, and this is one of the reasons why it is big.